# Get a total of field values in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, sum

So my code is

```
    if ($activities) {
      foreach ($activities as $activity) {
        $price = $activity['price'];
        if($price) {echo $price;};
      }
    }
```

and i would like to add the values of the $price field to get a grand total to echo

Comment: Declare `$price` before the loop, then increment it on each iteration, then `echo` result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real work goes on in this line, which increments the total every time the loop iterates (comes around): `$total += $price;`

```
$total = 0;
if ($activities) {
  foreach ($activities as $activity) {
    $price = $activity['price'];
    if($price) {
        echo $price; // do you still need this?
        $total += $price;
    }
  }
}
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a loop? I would use `array_sum()`.

```
$total = array_sum(array_filter(array_values($activities)));
```

[`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) returns all the values. [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) filters out anything that evaluates to false (like null or 0). [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) adds them up.

Functional programming is your friend. :-)